# Resolving own domain over SoftEther tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, softether

I have set up a VPN tunnel home using SoftEther software. For compatibility purposes, I've even setup a OpenVPN compatible server using the relevant setting in the SoftEther server management package.

Everything works correctly when accessing it over the Internet however when trying to connect over the corporate network of my work then everything works fine as well except the name resolving of my own domain name. The domain name IP is the same as the one I use to connect to the tunnel itself.

When I try to access a web site ex. mysite.mydomain.com then chrome says: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The only way to make it work is by using Acrylic Proxy so I can configure the domain names to resolve to local (192.xxx.xxx.xxx) IP addresses.

If I connect my work computer to my mobile phone using hotspot and connect to the tunnel again then it resolves my domain correctly without the need of a proxy.

The exact same happens using the OpenVPN server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your work network has any machine with the same IP as of your mysite.mydomain.com?

If so, work computer may redirect traffic to work machine and it may not be listing on particular services.

Comment: The IP is an Internet v4 and its the same IP as the one I use to connect to the tunnel to begin with. I can access my (sub)domain from my works network when not using the VPN. Its only when the VPN is connected that I cant access them using the Internet IP over the tunnel but I can access them using the proxy pointing to my internal LAN IP.